# How to capture the souce code of an onload modified webpage

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

Well, I was scraping data from one of the website (purely in legal limits).

The situation is that the site has 5 questions on a page and answers to them.But the source code that I see by pressing `Ctrl+u` is different from the code that I see by `Inspect element` or `firebug` in Firefox.That means the site is changing the answers on page load to fool the people around as scrapers would normally grab the unmodified code.The correct answers are on the `onLoad` modified page.

What I want is to capture the source code that I see in `Firebug` or `Inspect element` (the modified code) instead of the code that I see on pressing `Ctrl+U`.

I used one of the scraping API but it is capturing that original `Ctrl+U` code.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In chrome, select root element (<html>) and right click -> Copy as HTML, paste wherever

[EDIT]

I suspect you are trying to scrape the data automatically, this obviously won't work, not sure how to do this otherwise. There are some headless web browsers that support JS ([phantom js](http://phantomjs.org/) for example), they might do the trick. Also check out [this super user post](https://superuser.com/questions/448514/command-line-browser-with-js-support)

Comment: Yes I scraping the data automatically

Answer (score 0):

I'ld suggest you to do a log of the html of your page before the onload happens. Which can be done using jquery.

Or plain classic debugging using "debugger" which will stop the exec of your webpage once the line where you put it is interpreted by the browser.

As a HTML5 game dev, I usually do advanced logging through the console, to know what does what and what's executed when. Although it may take some time, it allows you to have a good comprehension of what you've written and to ensure optimization (mostly in number of execs of some stuff) and to catch bugs that might not be obvious.